# Project Euler 48 - How so avoid subscriptable errors

Tags: python

I'm attempting to complete [Project Euler 48](https://projecteuler.net/problem=48).

I ran into an issue where what I want to append is not subscriptable. How can I avoid this?

I have removed the for loop that appends to the list, and asked it to print out `n` and it works fine. When I put back the for loop and only tell it to append `n` to the list, it works, but when I try to append `n[b]`, the code fails.

```py
i = 1                     #Variable 1 to for the for loop coming later
n = 0                     #Variable 2 to collect to the sum of all the integers
Final = []                #List that the final 10 digits will be append to
for i in range (1, 1000):
  n = n+ i**i             #Groups the sum of the self powers into 1 variable


a = 0                     #Declaring variable for next loop
for a in range (0, 9):     
  b = -10+a               
  Final.append(n[b])      #To append n[-10], n[-9] to n[-1], etc to the list, final
  a += 1                  # So the value of b reduces


print (Final)             #Print results :)
```

What I expected was the last 10 digits of the sum of all the self powers from 1 to 1000, in order. What actually comes out is a substriptable error.

Comment: `n` is an `int`, so what is `n[-10]` supposed to do?

Comment: the error is basically telling you, `n[b]` is not a thing that's doable with ints. a different structure though, say lists/strings.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it : n is an int , so n[i] doesn't work.

What you are trying to achieve is get the digits , which you can access simply by asking the string of the number , and not the number itself :

```
digits = str(n)
```